# Backporting patch for Ruby gem

Tags: rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

I recently created a website using GitHub pages and ran into a minor bug where Jekyll incorrectly logs an error. I've noticed that a patch exists for it in the current stable version of Jekyll, 4.0. However, GitHub pages currently requires Jekyll 3.8.5, which still faces this bug.

I would like to fix it, and was wondering if I could somehow take the existing fix and backport it to apply it to the publicly available Jekyll 3.8.5 rather than just the local copy on my system.

Comment: In theory you could, you'd open a pull request against the 3.8.5 branch or tag of Jekyll, but it'd be up to their maintainers whether or not to accept it and publish a new 3.8.x version.

Comment: The latest version on the 3.8.x branch seems to be 3.8.6 as opposed to 3.8.5. The branch also appears to have been closed. Does that mean that updating 3.8.5 specifically is no longer possible, and rather continuing along 3.8.x is what would be standard?  If I understand correctly, then even if the patch did go through and they happened to increment 3.8.x by 1 just for this patch, there would still be the issue of needing GitHub pages to increment their dependency to the new 3.8.x? And that they haven't been doing so, judging by the fact they aren't using the latest, 3.8.6?

Comment: If they have that specific version deployed, then you are correct, it won't help.  If you don't control the versions installed and deployed, your options are more limited.  Sorry I don't know more about how their ecosystem is set up.

Comment: No worries. You’ve really helped me out. Thanks Joe!